# In Sybase ASE, sp_helptext shows suceeded but nothing else is displayed

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, ase

I am using Sybase ASE for the first time, and assume I am missing some very basic things.

```
sp_helptext 'dbname.procedure_name'
```

returns

```
'dbname.procedure_name' succeeded.
```

but nothing else.  A misspelling returns error.

How do I capture or display the results?

Thanks.

```
sp_version
```

returns

```
sp_version
```

I am using Oracle SQL developer with a plug in.  Would using other gui yield better results?
Is this a permission issue?

Answer (score 2):

Some background:

1 - the `sp_%` procs are stored in the `sybsystemprocs` database but available for execution from within all databases

2 - the `sp_help%` procs work on the `sys%` tables in the 'local' database

Putting these tidbits together ... you need to execute `sp_helptext` from within the `dbname` database in order to obtain the text of `procedure_name` (the stored procedure's text is stored in the `dbname..syscomments` table).

A couple ways to accomplish this:

```
-----------------------------
-- option #1:
-- place yourself in the database

use dbname
go

-- now run sp_helptext

exec sp_helptext procedure_name
go
-----------------------------
-- option #2
-- preface the sp_helptext invocation with the name of the
-- database in which you wish to run sp_helptext

execute dbname..sp_helptext procedure_name
go
-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, there's a newer sp_showtext command that shows the text without annoying line breaks every 255 characters.

Be careful with renamed objects.  The sp_helptext/sp_showtext output will usually show the old object name.

Answer (score -1):

SQL developer didn't display the results (probably didn't correct way to execute query).  Using a different gui solved the problem.